# Can I make a data structure appear as an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

By datastructure I mean a hash or an object. Here's an example (written in coffeescript but I'm sure you'll be able to follow):

```
left_arrow = { clickable : true }

$('.left_arrow').click ->
    console.log self.clickable /* want this to log 'true'
```

The HTML:

```
<div class = "left_arrow"> < </div>
```

Conceptually, this could be looked upon as mapping an element's class/id with a javascript object.

Comment: So you want your element to directly map to a JavaScript object?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is what I want!

Comment: This seems interesting, but I don't know of a way right off the bat. Frameworks like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) solve problems similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ah, it's only a tiny little (finished) project, I just thought it would be a neat way to do things :) If it aint broke don't fix it I suppose

Comment: So you want to map a dom element(s) to an object, via the class name?

Comment: Yes...maybe worded slightly poorly, but that would work. I was just wondering if this can be done, it's nothing crucial.

Comment: I suppose you could override the jQuery constructor, and merge any matching objects in scope, with the jQuery result.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the attributes you want to save, and since it looks like you're already using jQuery, use jQuery's [data method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to save them to the element.

```
attributes = {
  left_arrow: { clickable : true }
}

for attribute_name, attribute_data in attributes
  ($ ".#{attribute_name}").data attribute_data

# ...

($ '.left_arrow').click ->
  console.log ($ this).data('clickable') # logs true
```